# JavaScript cannot check checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/

Here is the javascript from the jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(event) { //line 1
        if(!$(event.target).closest('.menu').length) { //line 2
            if ($('.menu-btn').is(':checked')) { //line 3
                $('.menu-btn').trigger('click'); //line 4
            }
        }        
    })
})
```

as you can see, line 1 is to detect if a user is going to click on the page. line 2 is to detect if the user clicks on anywhere EXCEPT for the .menu element (which is anywhere in the black background). Line 3 is to detect if the .menu-btn checkbox is checked. if it is checked, it will trigger a click on the checkbox.

**So, here is the summary of the code:** if the user clicks on anywhere EXCEPT for the black box area and the checkbox IS checked, the code will trigger a click on the checkbox and it will uncheck the checkbox. **the problem is**, the checkbox does not even check at all. why is it not working?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/1/

Comment: Your handler is setup to trigger a `click` on the checkbox every time it's checked...so you're immediately unchecking it.

Comment: @Rayon now i can check the checkbox BUT i cannot uncheck the checkbox when i click somewhere outside of the black box area.

Comment: @AndréDion i don't understand, how do i fix it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to change your outer if check to

`if(!$(event.target).closest('.menu').length && !$(event.target).hasClass('menu-btn')) {`

The way you're doing it now is seeing if the click target has an ancestor with the `.menu` class, but if you click the *checkbox*, it will not have that ancestor. This means the outer if check will pass, then the inner if check will pass because the click you just did checked the box. That will run the line

`$('.menu-btn').prop( "checked", false );`

[Here's the working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/4/)

Comment: I do believe this is the answer the OP is looking for

Comment: Yes, thanks it worked but look here: https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/7/

I want to click on the label and check the checkbox. that works. but i cannot uncheck the checkbox is the label. how do i fix this?

Comment: You want to click the label to check or uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: exactly. I want to click the label to check and uncheck the checkbox. I ALSO want to uncheck the checkbox if the checkbox is checked and if the user clicks anywhere EXCEPT for black area box.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/8/ this one is all working except I cannot check the checkbox in the first place with the label.

Comment: Yep it looks like you got it, nice job.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to uncheck a checkbox with jQuery:

```
$('.menu-btn').prop( "checked", false );
```

Comment: oh i didn't know that but it still doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/56xh3rLo/2/

Comment: @pixie123 your jsfiddle seems to be doing exactly what it should to me. When you click on the checkbox, it's not in the menu. It is now checked, so your javascript unchecks it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit expressive, but I hope it will be more clear to the reader:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $btn = $('.menu-btn');

  $window.on('click', function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);

    if($target.is($btn)) {
      return;
    }

    if($btn.is(':checked') === false) {
      return;
    }

    if ($target.closest('.menu').length > 0) {
      return;
    }

    $btn.prop('checked', false);

  });
});
```